# Get facebook like count using php and FQL

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, facebook-fql

i would like to count total facebook likes for a URl and save it in mysql.

im using facebook FQL to get the count.

code

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

this method will return me a xml file with the following

```
<fql_query_response list="true"><link_stat><like_count>1548</like_count></link_stat></fql_query_response>
```

what i like to know is how to take only the like count as a sting. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all` for this

```
$string = '<fql_query_response list="true"><link_stat><like_count>1548</like_count></link_stat></fql_query_response>';

preg_match_all("/(?P<number>\d+)/", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches['number'][0]);
```

NOTE : Considering that there no other number there in string, If it is there need to change the preg match slitly :)

Answer (score 0):

As you know the structure of the xml, you can use SimpleXML. Code should look like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($your_facebook_response);
$count = $xml->link_stat[0]->link_count[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://www.stackoverflow.com"&format=json instead of your.

Hope that will help.